# Separating two divs with CSS

Tags: css, html, web

Say I have two divs A and B, which are currently aligned side by side. How can I get A to be separated from B by 50px, while still letting A to take up 70% of the remaining space and B the remaining 30%?

EDIT: Accepted the answer a little early before I actually tried. Whoops.

JSFiddles:

[A Tale of Two Divs](http://jsfiddle.net/aQQKB/)

[Now separated](http://jsfiddle.net/5bZtm/), but now with the second one on a second line?

Comment: _still letting A to take up 70%_... so you already have two divs with 70% and 30%.. why not show them - code or a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: you want to keep the divs size and add 50px margin between them? I either you enlarge the whole page size or reduce the width of one div.

Comment: use some percetange instead of 50px, e.g. divA:67% margin:5% divB:28%

Comment: @Nivas Heh, because I though it would be simple enough. `div.A {width:70%;} div.B {width:30%;}` would be it, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your selected answer will not work:

http://jsfiddle.net/cNsXh/

**edit:**
Sorry, the above example was not correct at first. Now it is.
**/edit**

As you can see, `div #b` will move under `div #a` because `margin-left` (or `padding-left`) will be added to the `30%`. And because we're mixing percentage with pixel values here, we will not be able to define values that will guarantee to always add up to exactly 100%.

You'll need to use a wrapper for `div #b` which will have `30%` width, and not define a width for `div #b`, but define `margin-left`. Because a `div` is a block element it will automatically fill the remaining space inside the wrapper div:

http://jsfiddle.net/k7LRz/

This way you will circumvent the CSS < 3 box-model features which oddly enough was defined such that defining a dimension (width / height) will NOT subtract margins and/or paddings and/or border-width.
I believe CSS 3's box-model will provide more flexible options here. But, admittedly, I'm not sure yet about cross-browser support for these new features.

Comment: @wrongusername: also keep in mind that border-width's will also be added to the precentage widths. This really is an annoying feature of CSS < 3.

Comment: @wrongusername: same principle; you'll need to use a wrapper element for `div #a` then as well with `width 70%` and ditch the `width` for `div #a`.

Comment: @wrongusername: You're welcome. And yeah: welcome to the CSS < 3 box-model. :-( That part about it really sucks unfortunately.

Answer (score 6):

Try this out if it solves your problem.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #Content
        {
            border: 3px solid blue;
            position: relative;
            height: 300px;
        }

        #divA
        {
            border: 3px solid red;
            position: absolute;
            margin-right: 25px;
            left: 5px;
            top: 5px;
            bottom: 5px;
            right: 70%;
        }

        #divB
        {
            border: 3px solid green;
            position: absolute;
            right: 5px;
            top: 5px;
            bottom: 5px;
            left: 30%;
            margin-left: 25px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Content">
        <div id="divA">
        </div>
        <div id="divB">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

just set the margin-left or padding-left of div B

Comment: margin-left will be better is the CSS have like shadow or border

Answer (score 2):

@wrongusername; i know you accept that answer but you can check this solution as well in this you have no need to give extra `mark-up` & if you give `padding` to your div it's not affect the structure.

CHECK THIS EXAMPLE:  http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/k7LRz/3/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/efortis/HJDWM/

```
#divA{ 
    width: 69%;  
}
#divB{ 
    width: 29%; 
    margin-left: 2%;
}
```

Comment: Sorry Eric, but I wanted a set distance between the two divs :)

Comment: @wrongusername Keep in mind that with fluid layouts you must sacrifice at least one dimension.  `100% + 50px` won't fit, so you better go with proportional spacing as shown or as @fireeyedboy suggested use `30% - 50px` for the last column.