# Robustly keeping two divs vertically separated

Tags: html, css

What's the canonical way to ensure an image and text are vertically separated from one another in a fully responsive way?

Look at this:

[image]

Via putting the image and text in separate `divs`, specifying `width` and ensuring `display:block-inline`, I'm able to create the following:

[image]

But this isn't perfectly responsive. How? For instance, for really small sizes (sizes that I must support), the image and the text run into one another like below:

[image]

There has to be a way to keep them vertically separated along any screen size. Perhaps I should use tables?

Please advise with an illustrative example, preferably with well-support CSS 2.1 attributes since a substantial number of clients I have to cater are Opera Mini browsers with no CSS3 or JS support.

---

My code is:

```
<div style="background-color:#E1F5FE;border-radius:10px;padding:10px;overflow:hidden;">
    <div style="width:20%;display:inline-block;">
        <img src="X.png">
    </div>
    <div style="width:80%;display:inline-block;float:right;text-align:center;">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ex eam nulla veritus abhorreant, magna vocent molestiae ea pri, ut eos tritani incorrupte
    </div>
</div>
```

This is a variant of the answers given to this similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523778/separating-two-divs-with-css). It doesn't really solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using `flex` with `flex-wrap: wrap` to take care of the responsive sizing. At small sizes the icon and text will stack vertically, and at larger sizes the icon and text will be horizontally aligned.

[Flex has great support these days](https://caniuse.com/#search=flex), even for the browser you mention.

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.imgDiv {
  flex: 1 1;
  min-width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  
}

.imgDiv > img {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 150px;
  line-height: 0px;
}

.textDiv {
  flex: 1 1 250px;
  display: flex;
}

.textDiv > p {
  flex: 1 0 0px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="imgDiv">
      <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/839721704163155970/LI_TRk1z_400x400.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="textDiv">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ex eam nulla veritus abhorreant, magna vocent molestiae ea pri, ut eos tritani incorrupte</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean 'skews'? I made it center the image on smaller screens, but that can easily be removed.

Comment: I meant it stretches the image, without keeping the aspect ratio intact.

Comment: Which browser are you seeing this on?

Comment: 55.0.2 Mozilla Firefox for Ubuntu

Comment: Btw different topic, but thought it's pertinent to ask. How do I vertically center the image and text in their place? I thought adding ` vertical-align: middle;` to `.main` would work, but doesn't.

Comment: Figured it out, it's `justify-content: center;  align-items: center;`

Comment: Making the `.textDiv` a `flex` container and adding `align-self` to the `p` tag works too.

Answer (score 3):

Simply add `width:100%` for the image

But check the whole `css`, on small screens it is better to show the div below each others

```css
.main{
  background-color:#E1F5FE;
  border-radius:10px;
  padding:10px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.main > div{
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
}
.imgDiv{
  width:20%;
}
.textDiv{
  width:80%;
}
.imgDiv > img{
  width:100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  .imgDiv{
    margin: 0 0 20px 25%;
    width:50%;
  }
  .textDiv{
    width:100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="imgDiv">
      <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/839721704163155970/LI_TRk1z_400x400.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="textDiv">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ex eam nulla veritus abhorreant, magna vocent molestiae ea pri, ut eos tritani incorrupte
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check my updated answer. Added a css for small screens where the div will be below each other. More user friendly

Comment: Problem with this is, it doesn't respect the image's aspect ratio, stretching and skewing it with changing view port.